# Python: C++ extension returning multiple values

Tags: python, c++, python-c-api, python-c-extension

I am writing a C++ extension for python script and want to return multiple values like what we can do in python function.

Simple Example in python:

```
def test():
    return 0,0
```

**tuple** seems to be the closest answer

```
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<int,int> test(void){
return std::make_tuple(0,0);
}
```

But when I compile it, it complains that

```
TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: std::tuple<int, int>
```

Anyone knows if I could return multiple values using C++?

**EDIT:**

This is my setup.py file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension

setup(name="PackageName",
    ext_modules=[
        Extension("foo", ["foo.cpp"],
        libraries = ["boost_python"],
        extra_compile_args = ["-std=c++11"]
        )
    ])
```

Comment: If you want to return a specific data type, like int or float, you can use array or std::vector of that particular type.

Comment: Python C Extension sucks... try ctypes... it's much better and widely compatible and not python version dependent, but needs more experience on C/C++.

Comment: How are you building the python C++ extension? I don't recognize the source of that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're using boost-python. Then should use boost::python::tuple, not std::tuple. See the examples on [this page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/object_wrappers/boost_python_tuple_hpp.html#object_wrappers.boost_python_tuple_hpp.introduction).